# Specify multiple reversed criteria for grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

In normal Semantic UI we can do this:

```
<div class="ui mobile reversed tablet reversed equal width grid container">
```

This will display the columns in reversed order on mobile and tablet resolutions. [Example](https://codepen.io/dhilgarth/pen/Naezay)

I am trying to achieve the same behavior with Semantic UI React and I fail to do so.

Here is what I tried:

```
<Grid reversed="computer tablet">
// or
<Grid reversed="computer,tablet">
// or
<Grid reversed="computer|tablet">
// or
<Grid reversed={["computer","tablet"]}>
```

All result in a similar error message:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `reversed` of value `computer,tablet` supplied to `GridRow`, expected one of ["computer","computer vertically","mobile","mobile vertically","tablet","tablet vertically"].

Is there a way to achieve this or is this a missing feature in Semantic UI React?

---

Currently, I am using the following workaround, which is super ugly:

```
const content = [<Grid.Row key="row1">...</Grid.Row>, <Grid.Row key="rowN">...</Grid.Row>]
<Grid reversed="computer" only="computer">
  {content}
</Grid>
<Grid reversed="tablet" only="tablet">
  {content}
</Grid>
<Grid only="mobile">
  {content}
</Grid>
```

Comment: I created an issue: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/2222

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `className` prop of the grid:

```
<Grid className='table reversed computer reversed' />
```

The prop is available as can be seen in this [doc](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid).

Comment: Maybe opening an issue would make sense, since your point seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. It's arguably less ugly than my workaround. I am going to open an issue as soon as I am sure I am not missing something.